# function not working for jquery load() content tags?

Tags: jquery

```
$(function(){
 $(".tiptip").tipTip();
});
```

this tooltip function is working for all links.But it doesn't work for what are loaded through jquery load() function.

I have experienced in live() function.I have used this function on content events(click,change,blur) loaded via load().

But i don't know how to use this for content loaded via load().

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the official reply to this question.
https://drew.tenderapp.com/discussions/tiptip/2

Answer (score 0):

You could use the callback function when the load completes:

```
$.load('test.html', function() {
    $('.tiptip').tipTip();
});
```